# Laravel Query with Auth:: User

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can i change my Code:

```
<?php $titles = DB::table('messages')->pluck('text');

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo $title;
}
 ?>
```

to receiver the data from user ID like:

```
FROM messages->title FROM THE USER WITH THE `id`
```

I want display all messages that one user has been send.

Thanks

Comment: Do you not have relationships set up? IF you don't you should as then you can do `$user->messages->received();` where `messages` is a relationship on the `user` model and `received` is a custom method on the `messages` model that returns only messages that have been received by the user rather than sent by

Comment: show your db schema, message and user table model, controller code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use relationships:

```
DB::table('messages')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->pluck('text')
```

Or you can define the relationship in the `Message` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And then load messages:

```
$messages = auth()->user()->messages;
```

Or just lazy load messages for current user for later use:

```
auth()->user()->load('messages');
```

Comment: Unless OP is using an "unconventional" schema, `id` would refer to the message id.

Comment: Great Thanks, and can i sort it in an List, one per line? And is also possible with this way to show conversation sort by creation date like: first line from this sender, the second line receiver?

Comment: @therubby to sort messages `auth()->user()->messages()->latest()->get()`. Or use `oldest()` instead of `latest()` if you want to show older ones first.

Comment: @therubby no, you can use it with the first query too. Put `latest()` or `oldest()` before the `pluck()`

Comment: Thanks for your help friend:)

Answer (score 0):

```php
DB::table('messages')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('text');
```

should do the trick

Comment: Great Thanks, and can i sort it in an List, one per line? And is also possible with this way to show conversation sort by creation date like: first line from this sender, the second line receiver?